# Rails3, use on_change with remote_function and pass parameters to the controller in a text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, textfield

So .. is it possible? somthing like that:

in a view

> f.text_field
>   :amount,:onchange=>remote_function(:url=>{:controller=>:expenses,:action=>:sum_total,:amount
>   => "¿¿ this.value() ???"}) %>

and in expenses controller, action sum_total get a parameter "amount".

I know I maybe need to add to routes.rb.. `match 'expenses/sum_total/:amount' => "expenses#sum_total", :as=>:sum_total, :via=>:post`

I have done somthing like this with a colection_select, and passing parameters like `"with="'parameter='+this.value()")` but with text_field seems no work

Thanks a lot

I have tried all combinations but with no result.